# Parsing pdf to populate tableview

Tags: iphone, parsing, pdf

I am working on an app.The requirement is I need to populate the tableViewCells based on a pdf file.Like for example the headers of the table view will be a topic name from pdf and the contents will be the data inside the header.
I tried googling out but didn't find anything useful.Earlier I thought of parsing the pdf but this approach doesnot seems to be useful because i didn't find any pdf parser useful.
The last approach I thought is adding the contents in a plist file and parsing that plist,but i know this is not best way to do it.

So guys please suugest some better approach.

Thank you